# Deleting a line based on user input in a .txt file that has delimiter :

Tags: shell, sed

I got a code that I wish to delete a line in a .txt file that is based on the user's input.

e.g

the item.txt contains

```
sword and shield:10:20:30
cloak and dagger:1:2:3
sock and shoes4:5:
very awesome things7:8:9
```

the user wants to delete entire line based on his input "very awesome things" regardless of upper/lower case as long as it matches

```
read choice1
sed -e $choice1/d item.txt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use grep with -i (to ignore case) and -v (retrieve everything except pattern) option as below:

```
grep -iv "Very Awesome ThiNGS" item.txt ##use "$choice1" instead of "Very Awesome ThiNGS"
Output:
sword and shield:10:20:30
cloak and dagger:1:2:3
sock and shoes4:5:
```

If you need sed solution, you could do something like:

```
sed -i.bak "/$choice/Id" test.txt
```

-i - inplace delete within the file and make a .bak before doing the change.
I at the end - to ignore the case.
d at the end - to delete the line.

Answer (score 2):

You got it right, but since `$choice` has spaces in it, you have to put it between quotes (also it's choice, and not choice1, and you have forgotten the first `/`):

```
~$ sed -e /"$choice"/d item.txt
sword and shield:10:20:30
cloak and dagger:1:2:3
sock and shoes4:5:
```

You can also enclose the whole sed expression:

```
~$ sed -e "/$choice/d" item.txt
sword and shield:10:20:30
cloak and dagger:1:2:3
sock and shoes4:5:
```

To ignore case sensitivity, juste add the `I` flag:

```
~$ read choice
VeRy awesome things
~$ sed -e "/$choice/Id" item.txt
sword and shield:10:20:30
cloak and dagger:1:2:3
sock and shoes4:5:
```

Comment: Hi thx for the help. I ran the script and it removed the entire line in the terminal but when i open the file the line is still there. how should i rectify this?

Comment: @ken With the GNU implementation of sed, you can add the `-i` option to modify in-place: `sed -i -e "/$choice/Id" item.txt`